# Unable to get a Expo Push Notifications Token

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on react native Expo's Push Notifications. I just started and unable to get the Expo Push notification token. 
I added the following code:

```
token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
console.log(token);
```

and getting the error "[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: The Expo push notification service is supported only for Expo projects. Ensure you are logged in 
to your Expo developer account on the computer from which you are loading your project.]".

I am running the project in the Expo App and I have created an account on Expo but still not getting the token.
Expo experts, please guide.

Comment: Hmm getting this but with a real device and only on some of the apps.

Comment: https://forums.expo.dev/t/unable-to-get-a-expo-push-notifications-token-for-ios/65901

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your terminal type: "Expo login"

Sign in with your username//password.

Run the project again make sure you use a real device.

Answer (score 2):

Register on Expo's official Site. or if you already have an account then...
then from your terminal type `expo login`
now login using your expo's username, password

after successful login, you are now able to use the expo push notification service.
in the terminal type `expo start` to start your app dev again!

Answer (score 1):

If `expo login` is not recognized use `npx expo login`

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in to EXPO, if you don't have an Expo account kindly register here: https://expo.dev/signup

After, you do the following

Stop the server,
In your Terminal type `expo login`
Now Login using your expo's username and password
After successful login, you will be able to use the expo push notification service.
In the terminal type `expo start` to start your app again